# How does associativity get twisted by elements of $H^3(G)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

In [Braided Monoidal Categories](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/JS1.pdf) by Joyal and Street, §6 a monoidal category is $V =T(G,M,h)$ built using a recipe:

- objects are are elements of $G$ ✓
- $V_0(x,y) = M$ if $( x=y)$ or else $\varnothing$ if $(x\neq y)$.

  - is it a concidence it looks like the [dirac-δ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function ?
  - Can you get an identity like $\delta(x-y) = \sum e^{imx}e^{-iny} $ ?
- composition is addition in $M$

  - below, should $x$ and $y$ be added or multiplied?
- tensor product is $ (x \stackrel{\mu}{\to} x) \otimes (y \stackrel{\nu}{\to} y) \to (xy \stackrel{\mu\nu}{\to} xy) $

  - It's not clear to me what kind of object $(x \stackrel{\mu}{\to} x)$ should be ?
  - $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not defined ?
- the associativity morphism is $h(x,y,z) = (xy)z \to x(yz)$ ✓
- the identity element of $G$ acts a a strict identity element of $V$ ✓

---

My main question is **how the associativity of $G$ is getting twisted by the 3-cocycle ?**  All my other questions on the page are subordinate to this one.

---

The examples I have in mind come from specific choices of $G$ and modules $H$ for discussion on a future date.

All I know about group cohomology is that it generalizes Carries in arithmetic:

- [carry bits and group cohomology](http://blog.mikael.johanssons.org/archive/2006/07/carry-bits-and-group-cohomology/)
- Wikipedia: [Carries + higher mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_%28arithmetic%29#Higher_mathematics)
- [A cohomological viewpoint of elementary school arithmetic](http://www.math.wayne.edu/~isaksen/Expository/carrying.pdf)

Comment: $\mu$ and $\nu$ are homs and hence just elements of M.

Answer (score 4):

To give a map h(x,y,z): xyz = (xy)z -> x(yz) = xyz is to pick an element of M.  This is going to give the element of H^3.  The pentagon axiom becomes exactly the cocycle condition.  Finally giving a tensor equivalence whose underlying functor is the identity is to give a bunch of scalars g(x,y):xy->xy and this shows that two such tensor categories are equivalent if the cocycles differ by a coboundary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $M$ determines the map $(xy)z \mapsto x(yz)$ ?

Comment: Hom(g,g) = M for any g.  In particular, Hom(xyz,xyz) = M.  So to give a map from xyz to xyz is just to give an element of M.